# Prevent webView from using cached response for concurrent requests

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, nsurlrequest

I have a simple Mac app which consists entirely of a single WebView, which always loads the same url.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    self.webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    [[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0]];

}
```

The webpage being loaded just returns a random number:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n" + Math.random());
});
server.listen(8000);
```

The Mac App is rigged up such that if I hit ⌘N, it opens a new window with a new webview.

If I hit ⌘N fast but not super fast (e.g. once every 4 times per second), it gets different response data each time (i.e. a different random number generated by the server-side `Math.random()`).

But if I rapid-fire ⌘N,  it will occaionsally get the exact same response from the server (i.e. duplicated random numbers in multiple web views).

Is there a way to disable this behavior? I'd like it to always ignore cache, regardless of quickly requests are made.